# Create module with managed file

Tags: 8, files

I wanna create a page in my module with file managed upload, such as [image] How make it? Show me source code please?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Writing a full module is too broad for a single question, there are various different things you need to know in order to get to the point in your screenshot. Take some time to follow some tutorials on module development, and when you have a more specific question about a smaller part of the implementation, that's when to ask here. If you're unsure, have a look through the information in the [help] which will let you know what's on/off topic here. Many thanks